# Find string in a large text with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called `data` in a PostgreSQL table that contains the following:

```
-----BEGIN HEADER-----
TYPE = PKCS#10
SERIAL = xxxxx
NOTBEFORE = Thu Sep  9 12:37:43 2010 UTC
LOA = 10
ROLE = xxxxx
RA = xxxxx
REQUEST_AUTH_USERID = CN=xxxxxxx
SCEP_TID = xxxxx
ARCHIVED_AFTER = Mon Nov 30 17:41:40 2015
_AFTER = Tue Jan 26 09:26:14 2016
-----END HEADER-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICWTCCAUECAQAwFjEUMBIGA1UEAwwLQ09QUzAwMDEzMDAwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3
.
.
.
.
bV0eG4rlMOgTPv6mqb9HHKFqi3dsDzZKfXyoAsLOyOkj+AWXmAfXG8enT4uqBJJf
AsrUuJyTwzvmfdcEgYxokI6FU/nAjgQpmLkuVrE=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

As we want to move to a different application, I only need the part beginning with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`.

I tried to extract this string with substring and position in a SQL query but even if I try to find the possition of this string with:

```
SELECT position('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' in (SELECT data from openca2.request where req_key = 3874))
```

I get a NULL value. I only can find examples where a part of a single string is extracted.

I don't know if the spaces are a problem. The part within the beginning and end header are not always the same.

Can this be done with a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT substr(
          data,
          position('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' IN data)
       )
FROM openca2.request
WHERE req_key = 3874;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT split_part(data, '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----', 2)
FROM openca2.request 
WHERE req_key = 3874;
```

If you want to keep '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' then use '-----END HEADER-----' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. Both solutions are working.

I just have notices when I tried your queries that I was searching for the wrong req_key ..... and where I have the right req_key my solution works also

```
SELECT substring(data, position('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' in (SELECT data from openca2.request where req_key = 3873)) +0 ,50000) from openca2.request where req_key = 3873
```

But yours look better as it is shorter :)

So this question is answered. THX again to you both.